# Multiple fabric curved text onjects in a single canvas

Tags: fabricjs

I'm adding multiple curved text in a single canvas with fabric.js. I have successfully added first object in canvas. But when I'm going to add second object in the canvas, object controls are displayed perfectly. But starting position of text is not at top-left corner of object. And I don't know that where is I'm wrong. If anyone knows this issue solution, then answer will be appreciated. Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="fabric.js"></script>
    <script src="fabric.curvedText.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

            var upperCurvedText = new fabric.CurvedText('Upper Curved Text', {
                top: 0,
                left: 500,
                textAlign: 'center',
                radius: 500,
                fontSize: 30,
                spacing: 30,
                originX: 'center'
            });
            canvas.add(upperCurvedText);

            var lowerCurvedText = new fabric.CurvedText('Lower Curved Text', {
                top: 1000,
                left: 500,
                textAlign: 'center',
                radius: 500,
                fontSize: 30,
                spacing: 30,
                originX: 'center',
                originY: 'bottom',
                reverse: true
            });
            canvas.add(lowerCurvedText).renderAll();
            canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(canvas.getObjects().length - 1));
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row canvas-container">
            <canvas id="c" width="1000" height="1000" style="border:1px dotted #000; border-radius: 50%;"></canvas><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should include source code of fabric.curvedText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved. As it was my mistake that I have used any old versioned fabric.js library. By linking fabcric.js cnd, it is solved.